# C# coding style: comments

Tags: c#

Most C# style guides recommend against the /* ... */ commenting style, in favor of // or ///. Why is the former style to be avoided?

Comment: Should be a community wiki...

Comment: @Brandon, cos the answer is a matter of preference.

Comment: Where is this so-called community wiki?

Comment: If you edit the question there is a tick box option at the bottom of the edit box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't say I have a strong view against either - but IMO the biggest issue is that `/*` and `*/` get messy if you have it nested, with the side effect that you can't copy/paste blocks around safely (quite).

You can too-easily end up with the wrong code commented/enabled, or can end up with it not compiling because you've ended up with a `/* /* */ */`.

If you copy a block of `//` around, no harm - just those lines remain commented.

Comment: They don't nest properly at all.

Answer (score 9):

One thing that /* */ can do that // can't is to comment an interior portion of a line. I'll sometimes use this to comment a parameter to a method where something isn't obvious:

```
        point = ConvertFromLatLon(lat, lon, 0.0 /* height */ ) ;
```

In this case the constant, 0.0, being passed as the third parameter is representing height.
Of course this might be better:

```
        double height = 0.0;
        point = ConvertFromLatLon(lat, lon, height) ;
```

(I'm more likely to use the /* */ intra-line temporarily, to just try out passing a specific value.)

Answer (score 7):

There are a few reasons to prefer // to /*.. */.

- As JaredPar mentioned, there are weird comment-nesting issues that can crop up with /* */ usage.
- If you ever write/wrote some code that processes source code files, you'll be really happy if the // method is all that you have to deal with.
- It is far easier to visually detect a large block of commented code with the "//" method, particularly if syntax coloring is unavailable.  In fact, you'll often see the individual lines in a /* */ block prefixed with a *, just to be safe.
- The XML commenting style that can be used to produce code documentation requires "///" to be used.

Answer (score 6):

One example that comes to mind is that it's possible to accidentally interrupt a `/*` style comment.  For example

```
/* This is the start of a comment that documents the 
   behavior of the +-*/ operators in our program
*/
```

This code does not compile, while the `//` variant would.  Also the `///` represents a specific style of documentation to which external tools respond differently.

Answer (score 3):

`/* */` is fine for multi-line code blocks. For instance at the top of a code file, copyright info etc.

`//` is easier for single line.

Always use `///` for at least all public members in a class as your XML documentation gets generated from that from which you can create help files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you comment as you want since most of us are commenting via shortcuts in Visual Studio.
I use `ctr+K, ctrl+C` all selected rows are comented and `ctr+K ctrl+U` to uncomment selected rows.

Comment: Isn't it CTRL+E, C and CTRL+E, U?

Comment: yes some VS has this combination but I don't know how mine uses that one for any installation I've made by myself.Something is with my Carma :).

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that "//" is just easier to type in than /**/

Comment: I always use the numpad / and * where they are right next to eachother without the use of Shift.

Answer (score 1):

I think `/* */` will eventually go the way of the Dodo because in Visual Studio you can just select a block of code and hit CTRL-E,C to comment it out using the `//` style.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+/ in Resharper or / or ' in CodeRush.

Answer (score 1):

I always use // for actual COMMENTS, while I save the /* */ for code I temporarily do not want to run for debugging/development purposes.

By using only //, then you can be sure you can comment out a large block of lines/methods etc without nesting comments and making your compiler cry.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because one requires explicit syntax on EACH line and one creates comments that can comment out large sections of code if the closing `*/` is not used. It's just not as safe.