# Keyboard shortcut for Visual c# block comment in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2015, block-comments

I know there is keyboard shortcut for single line(//....) 
commenting <kbd>Ctrl + K + C</kbd> and uncommenting <kbd>Ctrl + K + U</kbd> .

My question is that, **is there any default keyboard shortcut for block (/* ...... */) commenting and uncommenting? If yes how?**

And If there is no default block  commenting keyboard shortcut defined, So
**is there a way i could add my own keyboard shortcut for this? How do i do that?**

I have found lot of questions regarding commenting, but haven't found spoken about block commenting anywhere. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't. All you can do is highlight multiple lines and do Ctrl K + C / K + U as you mentioned. This will at least comment all of the selected lines. So it's similar behavior. I haven't yet used VS 2015, actually, but every other version works this way. Don't know about adding your own shortcut, unfortunately.

Comment: is there a way i could add a shortcut to do block commenting?

Comment: I know you can add custom shortcuts to existing behavior, but I don't think you can create new shortcuts with new behavior. You'd have to create a macro and bind that macro to a key, or drop a button for it on a toolbar somewhere. Not sure how you'd do this though, I scarcely use VS Macros.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859468/why-does-visual-studio-resort-to-single-line-comments-when-commenting-a-multi-li

Comment: There are numerous reasons why the style of comment with `/* */` are not recommended: - they cannot be placed inside one another, they can be mistaken in some cases by compilers as regular expressions.

Answer (score 11):

for me, in Visual Studio 2015 community edition, when I select full lines it will insert `//` comments. If I select the lines only partially (the first line is not selected from the very beginning or the last line is not selected till the end), it will insert `/*` comments. The shortcut is the same, `Ctrl + K + C`.

**Full lines selected:**
`These lines will
be commented with //`

Press `Ctrl + K + C`

**Result:**

`//These lines will
 //be commented with //`

**Partial lines selected:**
These `lines will
be commented` with /*

Press `Ctrl + K + C`

**Result:**

These `/*lines will
be commented*/` with /*

Comment: Is this really working? Or this /*.....*/ is limited to community version only? I have used VS 2000, 2015 & 2017 Professional version, but neither of them supports the block comment.

Comment: I just tested again and the behavior changed a little in VS Community v. 15.5.2: It will add /* only if you select partially **one** line. Otherwise it will add //.

Comment: In latest version of Visual Studio Code (Version: 1.29.1 (user setup)), ctrl+k+u is not working but ctrl+k+c only works like //be commented with // -- irrespective of selecting single or multi-line.

Answer (score 7):

1. I used [FeinCtrl](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2c3354bd-8efd-4ea7-9099-a5fd80ca4185) to list all available commands, and there are only two related to commenting code in/out: Edit.CommentSelection and Edit.UncommentSelection; there are no other commands that could do a block commenting.
2. You can add your own shortcuts to any EXISTING command by going into Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, selecting a command and assigning your new key combination.
3. If you search this site, you'll find a lot of reasons to NOT use block comments at all.

Answer (score 6):

If you have resharper, you can use keyboard shortcut

```
Ctrl+Shift+/
```

to put block comment around selected statements.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Just what I needed! It's worth noting that this acts as a toggle, so selecting the same text and repeating the keystrokes removes the comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use three /// to create...

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple block comment you can create the following C# command in [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) and assign a shortcut to it:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        ts.Text = "/* " + ts.Text + " */";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of Visual Studio Code (Version : 1.29.1(user setup)), you can try `Ctrl+/` for single line comment & `Shift+Alt+A` for block comment. If you can click on **edit** of your menu bar, there you should be able to find the necessary info.